# Figure and text get torn apart

Tags: spacing, graphics, vertical-alignment, two-column

So I wanted to do a multicolumn document with blocks of text and some image description. Because it is in a bigger document I do not wanna change the formatting of sections which leaves me using \textbf for the titles of my blocks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\vspace*{10mm}
\textbf{Text Headline}
\vspace*{3mm}\\
\noindent
Some long Text\\
\vspace*{25mm}
\textbf{Image Headline}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

But the problem I am encountering is that for reasons I do not understand the vertical space in front of the image headline gets halved and half is before the image headline and the half is in between the Image headline and the graphic. I have been manually offsetting the vertical space for 2 hours now... Please help me..

Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag8Y4.jpg

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document, which we ca test as it is.

Comment: `Some long Text\\
\vspace*{25mm}
\textbf{Image Headline}`   adds the space after the bold text. I would guess that you intended `Some long Text<blank line>
\vspace*{25mm}
\textbf{Image Headline}`  or `Some long Text\\*[25mm]
\textbf{Image Headline}`

Comment: I did extend it @Zarko. Thank you!

Comment: Seemingly I didnt save the edit. Thank you @DavidCarlisle

Comment: thanks (I changed it to `example-image` as that is generally available)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want? It is an MWE that uses a modified version of your code. I had to spend some time just to add all the necessary items to your code to get it to compile.

```
% spaceprob.tex  SE 580566

\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\vspace*{10mm}
\textbf{Text Headline}
\vspace*{3mm}\\
\noindent
Some long Text % \\

\vspace*{25mm}
\textbf{Image Headline}
%\begin{figure}[H]
%    \centering
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{image.jpg}
  \end{center}
%\end{figure}

Some more text.

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

In general it is not a good idea to use the `[H]` option to the `figure` environment as it is then no longer a float, which is the purpose of the environment. You don't put a caption on the figure contents, so just use the `\include...` with no figure environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the layout you wanted?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\vspace*{10mm}
\textbf{Text Headline}

\vspace{3mm}
\noindent
Some long Text

\vspace{25mm}
\textbf{Image Headline}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Changes: I put a blank line before every `\vspace` (you almost always need that or equivalently `\par`)  I used `\vspace` not `\vspace*` so the space is dropped if there is a page break, and I changed the image width to `\linewidth` as `0.5\textwidth` is too wide, it does not account for the space between the columns.